# Spring Hibernate - Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, transactional

#### Why am I posting this?

After several hours of search / analysis / getting paranoid I would like to share my fault with you - I nailed down my cause of the problem.

#### When did it happen?

- within the application server (in my case embedded tomcat) - tests had no problem
- on two specific @Services on which the methods got properly annotated with @Transactional

#### What was not the problem?

- Missing @EnableTransactionManagement in the @Configuration
- Some weired AOP issue, eg having no default constructor in a Service not implementing an interface (AFAIK this problem does not exist anymore since Spring 4.0)

#### What was the problem?

I am using a CustomPermisionEvaluator for Security eg for securing methods like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(null, 'SERVICE.ASSOCIATION.FIND_BY_NAME')")
public ResponseEntity<AssociationResult> findByName(@PathVariable String name) {
    //do stuff
}
```

For doing this I have to extend the GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration to get my CustomPermissionEvaluator into business. In there I used @Autowiring to get access to the beans needed for the permission evaluation. And guess what - this were those 2 @Services which the TransactionInterceptor ignored.

#### tl;dr

Do not autowire beans into GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration => they will not get intercepted properly afterwards.

Comment: It worked for me when I annonated the service classes with @ Lazy @ Autowired in my CustomPermissionEvaluator class.

Comment: @ Hubert and @KuldeepSChauhan ...thanks for this and @ Lazy annotation worked for me too :)