# Hibernate cannot obtain session anymore after enabling @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to implement ACL based authorization for a Spring web application. As soon as I add the `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` annotation to my security configuration class, the Hibernate transaction session handling breaks and whenever I try to save an object I get: `Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread`. I suspect that I misconfigured something related to my ACL cache, because the issue also disappears when I remove the related methods from my configuration (while still having my class annotated with `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)`). These are the relevant methods from my config:

```
@Bean
public RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy() {
    RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
    roleHierarchy.setHierarchy("ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR > ROLE_MONITOR > ROLE_USER");
    return roleHierarchy;
}

/**
 * ACL audit logger (print ACL audits to console)
 * @return
 */

@Bean
ConsoleAuditLogger auditLogger(){
    return new ConsoleAuditLogger();
}

/**
 * Caches ACL permissions to reduce database load
 * @return AclCache
 */

@Bean
SpringCacheBasedAclCache aclCache(){
    PermissionGrantingStrategy permissionGrantingStrategy =
            new DefaultPermissionGrantingStrategy(auditLogger());


    return new SpringCacheBasedAclCache(cacheManager().getCache("aclCache"), permissionGrantingStrategy, aclAuthorizationStrategy());
}

@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    return new EhCacheCacheManager(ehCacheCacheManager().getObject());
}

/**
 * Cache manager factory to create the cached based on the settings in "/WEB-INF/ehcache.xml"
 * @return EhCacheManagerFactoryBean
 */

@Bean
public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCacheCacheManager() {
    EhCacheManagerFactoryBean cmfb = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
    cmfb.setConfigLocation(new ServletContextResource(servletContext, "/WEB-INF/ehcache.xml"));
    cmfb.setShared(true);
    return cmfb;
}


@Bean
AclAuthorizationStrategyImpl aclAuthorizationStrategy(){
    return new AclAuthorizationStrategyImpl(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR"), new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR"), new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR"));
}

@Bean
AclPermissionEvaluator permissionEvaluator() {
    return new AclPermissionEvaluator(aclService());
}

@Bean
JdbcMutableAclService aclService() {
    return new JdbcMutableAclService(dataSource, lookupStrategy(), aclCache());
}

@Bean
BasicLookupStrategy lookupStrategy(){
    return new BasicLookupStrategy(dataSource, aclCache(), aclAuthorizationStrategy(), auditLogger());
}

/**
 * Returns an expression handler based upon the specified role hierarchy and permission evaluator
 * @return
 */

@Bean
public DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler(){
    DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(permissionEvaluator());
    expressionHandler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy());
    return expressionHandler;
}
```

I am using Spring 4.2.2, Hibernate Entitymanager 5.0.3, and Spring Security 4.0.3. The bloody thing has been bugging me for hours now and I just cannot find a solution. Any ideas what I am missing here?

Cheers,
Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I found a solution mainly because of this SO post: [Spring Hibernate - Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059372/spring-hibernate-could-not-obtain-transaction-synchronized-session-for-current).

The author concludes:

> Do not autowire beans into GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration => they will not get intercepted properly afterwards.

And this is exactly what happened. My `CustomUserDetailsService` bean was autowired in the security configuration class and the transactional `loadByUserName` method stopped working because the `TransactionInterceptor` ignored this bean.

Basically I moved all the ACL related stuff alongside the `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` annotation into a separate configuration file and all at once everything started working as it is supposed to (including the ACL based authorization). This gave me hell of a headache and I hope I can help someone with this solution.

Comment: Solved very similar issue, using the same approach. Removed all Autowired beans from @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity , and injected them using ApplicationContextAware.

Comment: It worked for me when I annonated the service classes with @ Lazy @ Autowired in my CustomPermissionEvaluator class.